# displayed equations with equation numbers in HTML (alignment problems)

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to typeset a displayed equation in HTML, together with an equation number.  The equation is rendered as an image, the equation number is given as text:

```
<p>some text
<span style="display: block">
  <span>(1.7)</span>
  <img alt="[some equation]" src="img.png">
</span>
some more text.</p>
```

The result is meant to look similar to how LaTeX would typeset a displayed equation:

- The equation number and the formula should be vertically centred, *i.e.* the middle of `(1.7)` should vertically align with the middle of the image.  I can achieve this using `vertical-align: middle`.
- the image for the formula should be horizontally centred within the width of the surrounding paragraph.  I can achieve this using `text-align: center`.
- The left edge of the equation number should horizontally align with the left edge of the surrounding paragraph.  I can achieve this using `float: left`, but only for the price of breaking the vertical alignment.

I can get either the vertical or the horizontal alignment right (see [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seehuhn/a6e2rf0y/)), but I failed to get both horizontal and vertical alignment to work simultaneously.  How can I get the equation number to display correctly?

The result is meant to be portable to different ebook readers, so I cannot use JavaScript to move things around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made couple of changes to your code. See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpqhm9wp/)

```
.displayed {
  margin: 1ex auto;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.eqn {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.eqno {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Amrinder